# How to annotate some text with stacked line segments

Tags: formatting, line

How would I go about achieving this type of type setting?

[image: Text with line segments pointing to annotations]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a more complete answer (from Luis Turcio one), I propose this one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{annotate-equations}
\begin{document}
    \tikzmarknode{n1}{\underline{This}} \tikzmarknode{n2}{\underline{is}} \tikzmarknode{n3}{\underline{some}} \tikzmarknode{n4}{\underline{text}}
    \annotate[yshift=-0.5em]{below}{n4}{some info}
    \annotate[yshift=-2em,xshift=.2em]{below}{n3}{some more info}
    \annotate[yshift=-3.5em,xshift=4em]{below}{n2}{other info}
    \annotate[yshift=-5em,xshift=6.5em]{below}{n1}{as well}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here is a possibility with `annotate-equations` which suggest it can also be done with `tikzmark`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{annotate-equations}
\begin{document}
\tikzmarknode{n1}{This} \tikzmarknode{n2}{is} \tikzmarknode{n3}{some} \tikzmarknode{n4}{text}
\annotate[yshift=-0.5em]{below}{n4}{some info}
\annotate[yshift=-2em,xshift=.2em]{below}{n3}{some more info}
\annotate[yshift=-3.5em,xshift=4em]{below}{n2}{other info}
\annotate[yshift=-5em,xshift=6.5em]{below}{n1}{as well}
\end{document}
```

[image]